# When issuing a new verified asset is there anything beyond hosting a stellar.toml file I should be sure to do?

Tags: assets, issuing, verification

I making some development plans and just want to be sure I'm not missing anything obvious. I've read this post [How is an asset verified?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/645/how-is-an-asset-verified)

So far, my intention is to list a new asset and have it verified by hosting a stellar.toml file on the appropriate domain as described here, https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/stellar-toml.html

For example, I'm curious if the domain listing stellar.toml need to have https certificates?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, HTTPS is a must. The issuing account home domain should be specified in TLD format without protocol (`your.domain.com`, not the `https://your.domain.com/`).

If your `stellar.toml` has correct format and is served with CORS headers, you are good to go.

Beyond that, check [Stellar Ecosystem Proposals](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol), a set of recommended best practices for Stellar ecosystem.

To get listed on the [StellarTerm](https://stellarterm.com/) and all other services that use metadata from StellarTerm directory, create a pull request [here](https://github.com/irisli/stellarterm/tree/master/directory).

If you have plans to use Federation, you might also want to improve the security with [DKIF records](https://lumenbox.org/).