# Stellar port verification still not sure why it’s not verified?

Tags: assets, stellar-laboratory, exchanges, verification

I’ve produced a token (Zi) Zioncoin in the labs and verified it with the stellarid.io fed server. However it doesn’t seem to be verified on the stellar port exchange.

https://zioncoin.org.uk/.well-known/stellar.toml i.e. to image and no verification tick for my asset.

Does the .htaccess file need to be in both route and toml fold?

Or could it be i’ve not made an offer for my tokens or set up trustline from another account to distribution account yet (trustline has been made from issuer to distributor but not locked encase I needed to change something).

Some help would be massively appreciated,

Kind regards 
Nathanofzion

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost [check out this](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/645/how-is-an-asset-verified?rq=1). Good explanation of how assets are verified.

Also, I have just setup my own coin to play around with this verification process.

The steps I took:

1. Add Stellar.TOML to my web domain
2. Add domain to my issuing account

Here is my asset on Stellarport: https://portal.stellarport.io/exchange/alphanum12/RobCoin/GBCKL7CUKYX5764JI4SGMU4IYQNYY3FONQWA2HMO4KKE5QYIMYXZTMJY/native/XLM/Stellar

Comment: Maybe summarize the article you linked?

Comment: @RubberDucky thought about it, but this is almost a duplicate of that question, ie that article is step-by-step of getting verified

Comment: Thanks Rob however step 1 and 2 have been done, my coin not verified on stellarport but is verified on stellar.exeprt:https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/Zi-GDBNNE67F54PTUZTCTOQYT5CQZFXA2AX6O5DCA5BVR653OP6KCWGG2Z7

Comment: This confirms toml and domain added

Comment: apparently once this is done a transaction on horizon needs to be carried out for it to effect the update in the next quorum set

Comment: Awesome, nice to know -- I assume this was resolved?

Comment: No, Just tried a new transition from source account in horizon i.e. if source account not locked, re-submit domain name in set options as new transaction. Now waiting 2 hours to see result

Comment: Stellarport support wrote: "Yes, we've encountered this issue before. It seems horizon doesn't always update the asset's toml url when simply changing it, you need to send an operation involving the asset afterwards for the changes to take effect. Please see: https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/427"

Comment: Well seems toml file was invalided, I was using Microsoft note pad to write the file. the issue was the utf-8 encoding auto add bytes or BOM.

Comment: Sorry I resolved this by using a real text editor notepad++ hope this helps others...

Comment: Here is my Asset on stellarport: https://portal.stellarport.io/exchange/alphanum4/Zi/GDBNNE67F54PTUZTCTOQYT5CQZFXA2AX6O5DCA5BVR653OP6KCWGG2Z7/native/XLM/Stellar